# Wix bootstrapper multiple hyperlink text

Tags: windows, hyperlink, installation, wix, wix3.5

My idea is to make multiple license terms link's with different name One of them should be "**license terms**" next "**diagnostics**". But then I try to change name I faced this issue:

[image]

Here is my code for this RtfTheme.XML:

```
        <Page Name="Install">
        <Hypertext Name="EulaHyperlink" X="94" Y="-100" Width="-11" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallLicenseLinkText)</Hypertext>
        <Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" Height="30" Width="300" X="120" Y="-67" FontId="3">#(loc.InstallLicenseLinkCheckBox)</Checkbox>
        <Button Name="InstallButton" X="160" Y="-30" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="InstallCancelButton" X="240" Y="-30" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">
            <Text>Cancel</Text>
            <CloseWindowAction />
        </Button>
    </Page>
```

Bundle.wxs:

```
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense" >
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
    LogoFile="Resources/banner.png" LogoSideFile="Resources/r2.png"
    ThemeFile="Resources/RtfTheme.xml"
    LocalizationFile="Resources/RtfTheme.wxl"
    LicenseUrl="http://opensource.org/licenses/ms-rl" />
    <Payload SourceFile="Resources/r2.png"/>

</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

RtfTheme.WXL

```
   <String Id="InstallLicenseLinkText">By installing you accept these &lt;a href="#"&gt;license terms&lt;/a&gt;</String>
  <String Id="InstallLicenseLinkCheckBox">Also include &lt;a href="#"&gt;diagnostics&lt;/a&gt;</String>
```

Maybe whom have same issue and know how can I fix this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your check box the size of the box itself with no text. Add a second `<Hypertext>` that is positioned right beside the check box.